# How to get address from latitude and longitude values in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps

I want to get the full address of the particular place, i have longitude and latitude values.

How to convert it to address, i am using Terra, but some times it's throw error like.

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException'
>   occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary

and my application was crashed.

**My code**

```
 try
        {
            _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

            _watcher.PositionChanged += _watcher_PositionChanged;
            _watcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

void _watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
        //MessageBox.Show("Latitude & Longtitude:" + latitude + "  " + longitude);

        client.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceAsync(new ServiceReference1.LonLatPt { Lat = latitude, Lon = longitude });
    }

    void client_ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted(object sender, ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

            Captured_Address.Text = e.Result;
    }
```

How to solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 7 you can use the REST Location api from Bing. See:

[Find a Location by Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx)